# Do baking soda or vinegar reduce toxicity?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, toxicity

Both baking soda and vinegar can be used to remove cigarette odor from cloth and surfaces, at least temporarily. Do they reduce toxicity of the third hand cigarette smoke too or just 'hide' the smell?

Answer (score 1):

The toxicity of cigarette is due to nicotine. Nicotine is not deeply modified by adding vinegar or baking soda. Such an addition changes nicotine into an ammonium derivate that suppresses its odor and smell, but it does not modify its toxicity. Nicotine and its ammonium derivate have the same toxicity.